# Cocoa NSXMLElement "quick termination"

Tags: xml, cocoa

Sorry I don't kw the term to describe this simple thing.

I followed [this](http://www.informit.com/articles/article.aspx?p=468381) article to make a xml document. But I want to make this

```
<node attr1="abc" attr2="123" />
```

instead of

```
<node attr1="abc" attr2="123"></node>
```

How can I do this? I can't find it in the doc and I don even kw how to google it. Thanks!

Comment: Why does it matter? All XML parsers should treat those two forms identically. The only real benefit to the short form is when humans type it.

Comment: The other benefit is that u could save some disk place if u hv thousands of files with totally millions of nodes =]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you create your NSXMLDocument you need to set up your tag type.  What you want in your case is the option NSXMLNodeCompactEmptyElement.  Something like this:

```
NSXMLDocument* doc = [[NSXMLDocument alloc] initWithKind:kind options: NSXMLNodeCompactEmptyElement];
```

alternatively you can get the XML out formatted this way using this call:

```
NSString* str = [doc XMLStringWithOptions:(NSXMLNodeCompactEmptyElement | NSXMLNodePrettyPrint)];
```

See [this link](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSXMLNode_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/20002408-SW26) for more information.